# AWS Cloudwatch logs ingestion to splunk using hec

Tags: amazon-web-services, splunk, amazon-kinesis-firehose, splunk-hec

AWS Cloudwatch logs can be delivered to Splunk using hec where Splunk instance is a SaaS instance. The solution uses kinesis firehose to deliver the logs to Splunk hec. My question is on the Splunk side we need to whitelist the entire AWS region CIDR (us-east-1 in our case). AWS us-east-1 CIDRs are 1000+. What is the best solution? should we whitelist the Splunk hec end point to the internet?

Comment: Where is your HEC sitting? Is it in AWS, or elsewhere? If you don't have one currently in AWS, it may be a good idea to setup an HF in each AZ you are using. I have dealt with architecture issues like this before, and would be happy to help you - but this question is not an especially good fit for SO :)

Comment: hec is inbuilt feature of splunk.

Comment: yes ... the HEC is a feature of Splunk. Where are your HEC(s) located?